# How to change the openwrt Makefiles in order to generate only one image

Tags: linux, makefile, openwrt

I want hack the [openwrt](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt) Makefiles so that it generates only one image after a `make world`(after `make world` many images are generated in the `bin` directory which slower the  build), could any one give me hint to do that, i mean in which Makefile exactly i have to make my changes

**EDIT**

In the include directory i find a file `image.mk`, here, there is a function called `BuildImage` within this function i commented the instruction:
`$(foreach device,$(TARGET_DEVICES),$(call Device,$(device)))` which seems to me the one responsible on the generation of the images. Unfortunately all the images are generated after `make world`, any explication why ?

Comment: you have to change in target makefile

Comment: @VivekD thank you for the feedback

Comment: @VivekD Could you pls give more details. i opened the Makefile under target i thought that i will find a list of targets there and by suppressing some of them i can get my single target compiled but it was not the case. could u pls exlplain more thx in advance

Comment: It's bit tricky. Try the makefile present in package/kernel/linux or target/linux/{generic,<boardSpecificMakefile>}

Comment: In the `include` directory i find the file `image.mk`, here, there is a function called `BuildImage` within this function i commented the instruction `$(foreach device,$(TARGET_DEVICES),$(call Device,$(device)))` which seems to me the one responsible on the generation of the images. Unfortunately all the images are generated after `make world`, any explication why ?

Comment: image.mk file is the recipe builder file, but it does not have the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

First get the target board

```
grep CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD .config
```

Edit target makefile placed in below path

```
<root>/target/linux/<target_board>/image/Makefile
```

Then compile the build.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, could you please give more explanation on what to edit in this Makefile ?

Comment: Look for function calls, i mean lines started with call command and comment the unnecessary Image build calls.